# JQuery Label Click and Select All Check Boxes Issue

Tags: jquery, html, xml, hyperlink, anchor

I am trying to make a simple SELECT ALL Check Box on CLICK of LABEL.

But only alert statements are processed on the click of the label... 
On the right side under Asset Types I have put a check box on click of which all the check boxes are selected. But is it possible to do it on a click of the label and not having the check box at all...

Also there is a problem with the Clear button which is a JQuery Element and on click of which there is no effect on the check boxes(ideally which must get submitted)...

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/checkbox.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />

    <title>Subscribe</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#selectAllTechAreas').click(function(){
                  alert('aaa');
                  $('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);
                }); // Tech Areas Select All click function

                $('#selectAllAssetTypes').tap(function(event){
                  /*$('.assetTypeCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);*/
                        /*alert("Select All Asset Types clicked");*/
                        $('.assetTypeCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);
                }); // Asset Types Select All click function
                $('#clearAllSelections').click(function(){
                    /*$('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);
                    $('.assetTypeCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);*/

                    // Problem with deselecting the HTML Checkbox with jQM element click
                });
        }); // document
    </script>

    <style>
        .divClassStyle {
                color: black;
                border: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: gray;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 2px;
                font-family: "Agfa Rotis Semisans";
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .listStyle {
                color: white;
                border: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                background: orange;
            }
            .headerPadding{
                padding-left: 15px;
            }   
            .footerPadding{
                padding-left: 15px;
            }
            .contentGrayBg{
                background: #e9e9e9;
            }   
            .floatLeft{
                width: 50%;
                float: left;
            }
            .floatRight{
                width: 50%;
                float: right;
            }
            .container{
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .case{

            }
            .contentGrayBg{
                background: #e9e9e9;
            }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- ******** Header **********-->
    <div data-role="header" style="padding-top: 0px">
        <table style="width: 100%; border: none;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left: 15px; width: 90%">

                </td>
                <td style="border: 0px">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left: 15px;">

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <!-- ******** Content **********-->
    <div data-role="content" class="contentGrayBg">
        <div id="categoriesTable">

            <div class="container">
                    <div class="floatLeft">
                            <table id="technologyAreas">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <fieldset id="techAreasCB" data-role="controlgroup">
                                        <legend style="font-style: bold; font-size:16px">Technology Areas:</legend>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="case techAreasCheckBox" /></td>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 40px">SAP</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="case techAreasCheckBox" /></td>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 40px">Oracle</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="selectAllTechAreas" style="color: orange; padding-left: 10px"><b>Select All</b></label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>        
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    </div>  <!-- Div Class Float Left -->

                    <div class="floatRight">
                            <table id="assetTypes">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <fieldset id="assetTypesCB" data-role="controlgroup">
                                            <legend style="font-style: bold; font-size:16px">Asset Types:</legend>
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="checkbox16" id="checkbox16" class="case assetTypeCheckBox" /></td>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 40px">Audio/Videos</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="checkbox17" id="checkbox17" class="case assetTypeCheckBox" /></td>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 40px">Documents</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllAssetTypes"/></td>
                                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label style="color: orange; padding-left: 10px"><b>Select All</b></label></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                </table>        
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    </div>  <!-- Div Class Float Right -->

            </div>  <!-- Div Class Container -->
                    <div style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 15px">
                        <a href="#" id="clearAllSelections" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" style="background: orange; color: white; font-style: normal; text-shadow: none; width: 45%;">Clear</a>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" style="background: orange; color: white; font-style: normal; text-shadow: none; width: 45%;">Submit</a>      <!-- Should'nt it be "Subscribe Now" as per given in the text desc above -->
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>  <!-- Content End -->

    <!-- ******** Footer **********-->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <div class="footerPadding">
            <label style="color: red; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px">Go to Accenture.com</label> <br/>
            <label style="font-size: 12px;">&copy; 2012 Accenture. All Rights Reserved.</label>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- Content Footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there should be a very small change in ur code... just try to change `$('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);` to `$('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', 'checked');`... It works for me :) and also change

```
$('#selectAllAssetTypes').tap(function(event){
   $('.assetTypeCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked); 
   .....
}
```

to

```
$('#selectAllAssetTypes').click(function(event){
   $('.assetTypeCheckBox').attr('checked', 'checked');
   .....
}
```

Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HdT6r/) and pls note thet i haven't done the code for unselectAll checkboxes :)

Comment: Yeah, this works... :) also.... just minutes before I tried to replace it by true instead of 'checked' and it worked... :) Thanks :)

Comment: yeah...that is also a right solution...since u have tried with 'this.checked' property, i just suggested this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is in:

```
$('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);
```

it should be

```
$('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', true);
```

In other word the way that you set checked attribute.